# Tagging words in sentences using user define dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, named-entity-recognition

I have a corpus of more than 100k sentences and i have dictionary. i want to match the words in the corpus and tagged them in the sentences

corpus file "testing.txt"

```
Hello how are you doing. HiV is dangerous
Malaria can be cure
he has anxiety thats why he is behaving like that.
```

Dictionary file "dict.csv"

```
abc, anxiety, disorder
def, HIV, virus
hij, Malaria, virus
klm, headache, symptom
```

My python program

```
import csv
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as SM
from nltk.util import ngrams

import codecs

with open('dictionary.csv','r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    myfile = open("testing.txt", "rt")
    my2file = open("match.txt" ,"w")
    hay = myfile.read()
    myfile.close()

for row in reader:
    needle = row[1]
    needle_length = len(needle.split())
    max_sim_val = 0.9
    max_sim_string = u""
    for ngram in ngrams(hay.split(), needle_length + int(.2 * needle_length)):
        hay_ngram = u" ".join(ngram)

        similarity = SM(None, hay_ngram, needle).ratio()
        if similarity > max_sim_val:
            max_sim_val = similarity
            max_sim_string = hay_ngram
            str = [row[1] , ' ', max_sim_val.__str__(),' ', max_sim_string , '\n']
            my2file.writelines(str)
            print(str)

csvFile.close()
```

my ouput for now is

```
 disorder 0.9333333333333333 anxiety
 virus 0.9333333333333333 Malaria
```

I want my output as

```
 Hello how are you doing. HIV [virus] is dangerous
 Malaria [virus] can be cure.
 he has anxiety [disorder] thats why he is behaving like that
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the lines on your `testing.txt` and replace those values, something like this should work:

```py
...
if similarity > max_sim_val:
    max_sim_val = similarity
    max_sim_string = hay_ngram
    str = [row[1] , ' ', max_sim_val.__str__(),' ', max_sim_string , '\n']
    my2file.writelines(str)
    print(str)

    for line in hay.splitlines():
        if max_sim_string in line:
            print(line.replace(max_sim_string, f"{max_sim_string} [{row[1]}]"))
            break
```

Comment: Than you bro, it really helped me a lot

Comment: bro, my text is in this format
  { Hello how are you doing. HiV is dangerous }
 {  Malaria can be cure }
  { he has anxiety thats why he is behaving like that.}
 {  i'm doing very well }

while i'm getting the output in new file in 
{he has anxiety[disorder'] thats why he is behaving like that.
{ i'm doing very well
{ Malaria [virus'] can be cure }
{ Hello how are you doing Headache[symptom'] is dangerous }

the sentences are misplaced. Is it possible to keep the same order of sentences in  ".txt" file and replace the words?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you are building the output based on `dict.csv` that's the order that you should be getting. Of course, it can be changed. Create a question for it because answering it in the comments it's very complicated. @SubhaanKhan

Comment: Thank you for your continuous help. i will create another question for it.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568952/tagging-words-in-sentences-using-dictionares)
kindly have a look to my question. 
thanks